# Random "Cannot parse url" using LDAP authentication in Java

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jndi

I am trying to authenticate user using LDAP authentication in Java. Below is the code snippet where value of userDn is `"uid=myid,ou=People,o=ABC GROUP,o=Companies,dc=abc,dc=com"`

```
try {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVER_URL + userDn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, PASSWORD);
        userContext = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Naming exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code is working fine in test environment, but on production it is giving error for some of the users intermittently. Most of the time (~90%) it works for "same" user, but getting below error sometimes.

```
"Cannot parse url: GROUP,o=Companies,dc=abc,dc=com"
```

This error is not consistent. It is not reproducible on test enviornment.

I tried removing userDn (since it contains Space which maybe causing issue) in PROVIDER_URL like below which is also working on test environment but not on production.

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVER_URL);
```

On production, it is giving "Invalid Credentials" error after the above change.

Any idea what can be the possible root cause for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's weird you don't get the error consistently, but is for sure related to an URL encoding issue.

As the error says *"Cannot parse url: `GROUP,o=Companies,dc=abc,dc=com`"*, it looks like the space in `ABC GROUP` has not been escaped.

From the [LDAP URL Format (RFC-2255)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2255) specification :

> Note that any URL-illegal characters (e.g., spaces), URL special
> characters (as defined in section 2.2 of RFC 1738) and the reserved
> character '?' (ASCII 63) occurring inside a dn, filter, or other
> element of an LDAP URL MUST be escaped using the % method described
> in RFC 1738 [5].

So you need to explicitly escape spaces and any other URL special characters, for example (assuming `SERVER_URL` contains a trailing `/` :

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVER_URL + "o=ABC%20GROUP,o=Companies,dc=abc,dc=com");
```

Comment: I tried to escape this but now getting error for userDn "uid=myid,ou=People,o=ABC%20GROUP,o=Companies,dc=abc,dc=com"

[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]